# Normal matrices with constraints on eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find two different transformations with an inner product that follows these rules:
(I don't study math in english so I'll try my best to explain)

1)

a. $TT^*=T^*T$ (normal)
b. All eigenvalues are in $\mathbb{R}$ 
c. $T\neq T^*$ (not self-adjoint)

2) 
a. $TT^*=T^*T$ (normal)
b. All eigenvalues $\lambda$ satisfy $| \lambda| = 1 $ 
c. $TT^* \neq I$ ($T$ isn't unitary)

More than an answer I would be happy to hear an explanation as to how to approach something like this? (and not "brute forcing" every matrix I can think of and checking)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any such examples.

Every [normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) $A$ can be written in the form $A=U\Lambda U^*$ where $U$ is unitary and $\Lambda$ is diagonal. The diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$.

Therefore,

1. A normal matrix with real eigenvalues is self-adjoint
2. A normal matrix with unimodular eigenvalues is unitary.

Comment: That is assuming that F=C, but there can not be any complex eigenvalues when F=R.

Comment: @user168732 Since you stated "all eigenvalues are real" as a condition, I could only suppose you work over complex number.

Comment: Turns out it was a trick question :\